# App worked locally but not accessible externally with webpack server

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, webpack, ethereum

Hi I've been struggling for a while to figure out how to make an app on an AWS Windows server 2016 instance publicly accessible. My Ec2 traffic has been opened for inbound 8080. netstat shows 8080 is listening. The app can run on localhost on the EC2 by running command `"npm run dev"` but cannot be accessed publicly.

webpack.config.js:

```
    const path = require('path');
    const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
    module.exports = {
      entry: './app/javascripts/app.js',
      output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
      filename: 'app.js'
    },
    plugins: [
    // Copy our app's index.html to the build folder.
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      { from: './app/index.html', to: "index.html" },
      { from: './app/javascripts/browser-solc.min.js', to: "browser-solc.min.js" }
    ])
    ],
    ...
```

In package.json:

```
    "scripts": {
        "lint": "eslint ./",
        "build": "webpack",
        "dev": "webpack-dev-server",
        ...
```

I tried to modify `"dev": "webpack-dev-server"` to be `"dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --port 8080 --hot --host ec2_public_DNS_address"`, the console said it's run on the DNS with port 8080 open but I still cannot access it publicly.

Please help!

Comment: You have to use your local IP (the instace's IP in the VPC/subnet) not the public ip. Public IP redirects traffic to local IPs.

Comment: I tried public IP, public DNS, private IP and private DNS. None of them worked. netstat showed that the port of corresponding IPs were listening correctly.

Comment: Are you abble to load the page from the instance with the localIP? I mean via remote desktop open the browser or shell and load the page from that with the **local IP**, if you can do it it is a redirect issue, otherwise it is a app config issue.

Comment: No I cannot access the page via local IP. It only works with localhost:8080 (remote desktop localhost too). I guess you're right that it's an app config issue. Don't know how to address the config issue though. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yeah! It looks like a config issue, app or OS firewall. Can you run ifconfig shell command to verify you are using the right LOCAL IP in the --host parameter? Regards,